# Applying theme on GNU GRUB 2.06 for windows

Tags: windows-7, grub, themes, grub2, gnu

Hello everyone is there anyway to make gnu grub themes working in windows? I setup the Gnu grub 2.06 for windows (not grub2win) but I'm confused how to setup a theme which was easy in linux by adding

GNU_THEME= /boot/grub/themes/starlight/theme.txt

in grub (starlight is the theme folder), so in windows what i have tried so far is put theme under c:/grub/themes/ (that's where grub is installed on legacy pc) and add

GRUB_THEME=c:/grub/themes/starlight/theme.txt

in grub.cfg but theme but didn't work

Also tried to change with following one by one

GRUB_THEME=c:\grub\themes\starlight\theme.txt

GRUB_THEME=/grub/themes/starlight/theme.txt

GRUB_THEME=\grub\themes\starlight\theme.txt

But none of them work and starlight theme come pre install in the grub2 but not applied (also tried some available on internet still same results).

I don't use grub2win because it break easily and ask for chkdsk on boot to repair, so if anybody know how to apply theme in gnu grub 2.06 for windows would be so helpful.